# No text/link for suggested edit for orphan wiki

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page, orphaned-wiki

There is no text/link in the [suggestions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245360/patrick-hofman?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) for "orphan wiki":

[image: suggested on <empty>]

Comment: Well, that's terrible and all, but you can get to the revisions for that post by just clicking *approved edit* on the left and *orphan wiki* from the review page.

Comment: @NathanTuggy agreed, but I think empty space should be filled with something. Otherwise sentence is not finished.