# What are the empty posts from the Community user on the activity tab?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, community-user, orphaned-wiki

There are some empty posts from the Community user [in its activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=posts):

> [image: Empty posts]

What are those? If it's something deleted should it be marked appropriately instead of leaving the rows blank?

Answer (score 9):

I can answer what those are: they're [orphan wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148926/295232). So this is perhaps another variation of [Orphaned tag wiki edits have broken activity entries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148928/295232).

It turns out you can find the post IDs via the browser tools:

[image]

and navigating to e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359539/revisions will confirm:

[image]

You can even try to edit them (for science). It looks like [this suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76702) created the post (found with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1455331)).

The posts are not deleted (and even continue to give +2 reputation for suggested edits, IIRC). The problem seems not limited to Community, see e.g. [this page on my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) – but you noticed that [a couple of years ago already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287097/295232).

Comment: I suppose that they were created when somebody suggested an edit and it was rejected. For example, [trying the id from your post](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1086014/list-of-reviews-for-a-specific-post?postid=359539) leads to [this suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76702). A similar situation as here: [Why wasn't this tag removed - despite having single occurrence?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325118#325124)

Comment: Actually, the suggested edits page - the problem was that it was already selected for me. I've edited the link. In my case, the suggested edit was approved.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks, but in case of Glorfindel's profile I can unfold the item to see the content.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I can do the same on one of the items from community. I guess the difference will be between the suggested edit being accepted or declined. See the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aibSn.png).

Comment: @Luuklag actually, that was my science :)

Comment: Wow, you found [my old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287097/339911) "Asked 4 years, 9 months ago", so a couple of couple of years!